# Рекурсивный обход массива (phalcon)

Tags: php, foreach

```
 <?php

    $n=0;
    function data($parent_id, $robots2, $n, $type_id) {
        $n++;
        foreach ($robots2 as $robot):
            if ($robot->parent_id==$parent_id): ?>
                <p style = "margin-left:<?php echo 1+$n;?>%"><?php echo $robot->name;?></p>
                <?php
                    data($robot->id, $robots2, $n, $type_id);
                ?> 
            <?php endif;
        endforeach;
        $n--;
    }
?>
```

Дальше полной вложенности первого элемента не идет.
т.е. 
Элемент 1
   Элемент 1.1.
      Элемент 1.1.1
А Элемент 2 и т.д не выводятся. Подскажите, люди добрые, что делать...

Comment: Foreach не заканчивает предыдущий перебор после того, как закончил вложенный. Как его продолжить?

Comment: Алгоритм рабочий, видимо ошибка методе перебора содержимого объекта. На массиве все работает хорошо. Буду курить мануал по phalcon

Answer (score 1):

```
$n=0;

function data($parent_id, $robots2, $n, $type_id) {
    $n++; // здесь 1
    foreach ($robots2 as $robot):
        if ($robot->parent_id==$parent_id):?>
            <p style = "margin-left:<?php echo 1+$n;?>%"><?php echo $robot->name;?></p>
            <?php
                data($robot->id, $robots2, $n, $type_id);
            ?> 
        <?php endif;
    endforeach;
    $n--; // здесь опять 0
}
```

Comment: Ну да, каждый запуск функции - смещение вправо на 1%, если вложений нет, то следующая позиция идентична предыдущей (без табуляции)

Answer (score 0):

Перестаньте мешать HTML и PHP таким образом есть функции форматирования(printf/sprintf).

1. Убрал ненужние инкременты/дикременты.
2. Почистил мешанину в коде.
3. Добавил тестовые данные.

ПС: к `phalcon` не имеет отношения.

```
<?php

function data($parent_id, $robots2, $n, $type_id)
{
    foreach ($robots2 as $robot) {
        if ($robot->parent_id==$parent_id) {
            printf(
                // %% - escaped %.
                '<p style = "margin-left:%s%%">%s</p>%s',
                $n + 2,
                $robot->name,
                // New line constant
                PHP_EOL
            );

            data($robot->id, $robots2, $n + 1, $type_id);
        }
    };
}

// Test data
$robots = [
    (object)['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name'=> 'r 1'],
    (object)['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name'=> 'r 2'],
    (object)['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'r 3'],
    (object)['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name'=> 'r 4'],
    (object)['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name'=> 'r 5'],
    (object)['id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name'=> 'r 6'],
];

data(0, $robots, 0, 1);
//var_dump($robots);
```